# Absolute values (definition proof)

Tags: solution-verification, absolute-value

Prove that:
a) $x \le |x|$ and 
b) $|xy| = |x||y| $

Attempt:
a) If $x \ge 0: x = |x| \le |x|$. 
If $ x < 0: x = |-x| = |x| \le |x|.$

b) If $xy \ge 0: |xy| = xy = |x||y|.$ 
If $xy < 0: |xy| = -xy = |-x||y|$ or $|x||-y| = |x||y|$.

Is there anything that is wrong?

Comment: Of course it's correct

Comment: It’s not correct that $x=|-x|$ if $x<0$

Comment: @ J.W. Tanner What should it be?

Comment: it could be $x<-x=|x|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Your "attempt" is correct.

(Note that if $xy \geq 0$, we can also have $x < 0, y < 0$, but the statement still holds.)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to check if I understand the material. Just wanted to check. :)

Comment: yep, it has a timer cool down before I can accept anything.

Comment: thats okay, you can just wait

Answer (score 0):

If any of the variables is $0$ then the product are zero so the equality is true. Hence, we assume $x,y \ne 0$

---

Assume $x < 0$ and $y < 0$. Then $xy>0$ which means $$|x||y| = (-x)(-y) = xy = |xy|$$
The case $x > 0$ and $y>0$ is the same.

---

Assume $x>0$ and $y<0$. Then $xy < 0$ which means $$|x||y| = x(-y) = -xy = |xy|$$
The case $x<0$ and $y>0$ is the same.

Comment: The OP asks for what is wrong, not another proof of the same thing.

Comment: Very helpful as well. But I wanted to validity that I understood the concept. :)